# Laravel advanced query with multiple inputs

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have some search with multiple arguments and I want to query if the input is not null then make query argument.

I tried many ways but I cannot get query results.

Here is my sample code

```
$products = Product::where('game_id',$tg->id);
        if($keyword !=null){
            $products->where("name","like",$keyword);
        }
        if($price_start !=null){
            $products->where("price",">",$price_start);
        }
        if($price_end !=null){
            $products->where("price","<",$price_end);
        }
        if($avalibility !=null){
            $products->where("status","=",$avalibility);
        }

        $products->orderBy("created_at","DESC");
        $products->get();
```

Comment: You are not doing anything with the result of `$products->get()`

Comment: add `->get();` after all queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 $products = Product::select('*')
                ->where(function ($query) use($request){
                            if($keyword !=null){
                                $query->where('name','like','%'.$keyword.'%');
                            }
                            if($price_start !=null){
                                $query->where("price",">",$price_start);
                            }
                            if($price_end !=null){
                                $query->where("price","<",$price_end);
                            }
                            if($avalibility !=null){
                                $query->where("status","=",$avalibility);
                            }
                        })
                ->where('game_id',$tg->id)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->get();
```

Comment: This method worked for me. Thank you and others all. You Saved My Time

Answer (score 2):

In your code assign the result of query to the variable products as follows:

```
$products = $products->get();
```

now the $products will contain the result

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `->get()` to the query builder.

`$products = Product::where('game_id',$tg->id)->orderBy->('created_at', 'desc')->get()`.

Use the explicit `->get()` on the query builder to get a collection. And then use laravels collection 
methods (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods) to add further where clauses and sort the results (see sortBy method) or add the orderBy clause to the intial query (as above). You can leave out the final `->get()` since it's called on the query builder.

Using the 'where' collection method inside the if statement:

```
if(isset($keyword)) {
    $products = $products->where('name','like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to `validate` your data as follow

```
$request->validate([
    'id' => 'required',
    'keyword' => 'required',
    'price_start' => 'required',
    'availability' => 'required'
]);
```

Now you can perform your data query with these `validate Data`. If you have multiple data for **`where` method** you might be put all of them in array ,after that to `fetch` the data-you should use `get()` method; like as bellow

```
$products = Product::where([
              ['id', '=', $request->id],
              ['keyword', 'like', $request->keyword]
            ])
            ->orderBy("created_at","DESC")
            ->get();
```

Comment: Arguments do not need to validate because query must run if required some inputs